# android.view.InflateException on Activity.setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I am getting from time to time an exception in my app, apparently only happening in 2 Lenovo phones (S850 and B8080 - using Android 4.4). I don't own those phones; this is information I have seen in the Google Play Console. It is working fine in all other devices, including other ones using Android 4.4.

The exception doesn't seem to give exact details of the issue, and Android Studio doesn't give any warnings in this piece of code or the layout.

I have checked other threads and they seem to be different issues, mostly with the exception saying something about "Binary XML file line", message which doesn't appear in my case.

Any hint to debug this?

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2198)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2248)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:138)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5054)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:788)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:604)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:620)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:696)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:755)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:492)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:397)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:353)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout (PhoneWindow.java:3097)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor (PhoneWindow.java:3226)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView (PhoneWindow.java:298)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView (Activity.java:1929)
  at org.dreamcoder.nightearth.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:32)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5231)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1110)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2162)
```

Snippet of MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_banner);

    // Analytics
    AnalyticsHandler.init(this, AnalyticsHandler.ScreenName.MainActivity);

    // Initialise the ads
    Log.i("MainActivity", "Initialising Ads");
    AdsHandler.CreateBanner(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Where line 32 is the one doing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_banner);`

And the layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <!--<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>-->

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <!-- The ad -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

    <!-- The backup ad -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <!-- Some text -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/removeads"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <!-- Google Play image -->
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:src="@drawable/android_app_on_google_play"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:maxHeight="70dp"
            android:maxWidth="180dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is `AdView` class is jumb to that class by clicking `ctrl` from xml  ?

Comment: Yes. I get a dialog that I need to accept the terms and conditions of the JetBrains Decompiler, and once I accept the AdView class is shown.

Comment: which dialog is come ? In my code it don't come any dialog!

Comment: Android Studio 3.0.1 is the one showing this dialog. Anyway, the thing is that the class can be opened with ctrl+click.